# How to dynamically change selection of dropdown

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a master/detail scenario where upon selecting a product, the detail is displayed. The detail screen contains a dropdown containing various colors that could be selected to change the color of the product being displayed.

The dropdown data source is a static array that populates the dropdown in a fixed order -- white, black, black-on-steel, for instance. So irrespective of the color of the product that is first selected, the first selection of the dropdown is always white. I would like it to reflect the color of the product selected.

To make a long story short, how do I dynamically select the options of a dropdown?

This is the segment of code that creates the dropdown.

```
       <div class="panel-body form-group">
          <p-dropdown [options]="colors" [(ngModel)]="selectedColor" 
            name="selectedColor" (onChange)="changeProductColor()">
            <ng-template let-color pTemplate="item">
              <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
                <img src="..\assets\image\{{color.value}}.jpg" />
                <div>
                  {{color.label}}
                </div>
              </div>
            </ng-template>
          </p-dropdown>
        </div>
```

Comment: there is unknown bracket [ before (onChange)

Answer (score 0):

I am using a temporary solution by recreating the colors array dynamically and setting the desired color as the first element of the array. Filtering the array would be a better approach but couldn't get it to comply so I resorted to for loops.

```
    filterColors(color: string) {
    let tmp: SelectItem[] = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < this.colors.length; i++) {
      if(this.colors[i].value == color) {
        tmp[0] = this.colors[i];
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0, t=1; i < this.colors.length; i++) {
      if(this.colors[i].value !== color) {
        tmp[t++] = this.colors[i];
      }
    }

    // console.log("xxx = " + this.colors.filter(color => color.value == color));
    this.colors = tmp;    
  }
```